# what the meaning of the character '|' after 'run: ' in the yml file of github action?

Tags: yaml, github-actions

what the meaning of the character '|' after 'run: ' in the yml file of github action?
i need to understand that.thanks
here is code seg:

- name: npm install
  run: |
  npm install
  env:
  CI: true

  ```
  # 运行脚本
  - name: 运行脚本
    run: |
      COOKIE='${{ secrets.COOKIE }}' DINGTALK_WEBHOOK='${{ secrets.DINGTALK_WEBHOOK }}' DINGTALK_SECRET='${{ secrets.DINGTALK_SECRET }}' ALL_IN='${{ secrets.ALL_IN }}' WX_COMPANY_ID='${{ secrets.WX_COMPANY_ID }}' WX_APP_ID='${{ secrets.WX_APP_ID }}' WX_APP_SECRET='${{ secrets.WX_APP_SECRET }}' FEISHU_WEBHOOK='${{ secrets.FEISHU_WEBHOOK }}' FEISHU_SECRET='${{ secrets.FEISHU_SECRET }}' npm start
    env:
      CI: true
  ```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html) :

> Values can span multiple lines using `|` or `>`. Spanning multiple lines using a “Literal Block Scalar” `|` will include the newlines and any trailing spaces. Using a “Folded Block Scalar” `>` will fold newlines to spaces; it’s used to make what would otherwise be a very long line easier to read and edit. In either case the indentation will be ignored

Comment: Just to make perfectly clear: `|` and `>` are yaml constructs and not specific to GitHub actions.

Comment: Ahh, @DavidS, good point, thanks! For someone (like me) new to both GHA and YAML, this was not at all obvious at first sight.